# Real life applications of Cauchy Sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences, applications

What are some examples of real life applications of Cauchy sequences?(examples that could be modeled.) I read somewhere that the long term effects of weather on a construction could be modeled by a Cauchy sequence. Is it true? How is there convergence? Or could you give any other examples?

Comment: The importance of Cauchy sequences: in a complete space Cauchy $\implies$ convergent. And in the Cauchy condition the limit is missing. *We can prove convergence without knowing the limit*.

Comment: Sometimes the practical application of a concept is in the confirmation and reinforcement of other ideas (e.g. for set theory). Cauchy sequences are ubiquitous,  so it could cause a problem if we found out they had some nasty properties. But moreover,  there is sometimes no prior justification for exploring a mathematical object other than intrigue...

Comment: One might as well ask, "what is the real world application of convergence?"  Have you never run an iterative computation before?  Newton's method?

Comment: Without an understanding of convergence, a large swathe of mathematics and mathematical physics falls to pieces.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly no direct real-life application of Cauchy's Sequence. But if you go through [Banach Contraction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) then you may find some examples which have application in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Some intersting real life applications of Cauchy's Sequences are mentioned [here](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2017/02/21/cauchy-sequences-in-the-real-world/): sensor data, stock market quotes, speech signals. In his book *"A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing: The Sparse Way"*, Stephane Mallat uses Cauchy's Sequences as well. Béla Lantos and Lőrinc Márton utilize them too, see their book *"Nonlinear Control of Vehicles and Robots"*. I assume you will find a lot other examples in the area of Physics that are linked to industrial applications.